# ZScript FileExecute to DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, zscript

In ZScript for **ZBrush**, you can invoke a DLL using [`FileExecute`](http://pixologic.com/home/z2coderef.html#FileExecute)

```
[FileExecute,"ZBRUSH_ZData\ZPlugs\WebZPlug.dll",HTTP_Browse,"http://www.zbrushcentral.com"]
```

What is the DLL's entry point (C/C++ function) signature to receive arguments and data from ZScript? Are there any undocumented arguments to marshall data structures between ZScript and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviving some documentation which partly answer this question: here's the complete `FileExecute` signature:

```
[FileExecute, Filename, Function to call, Optional text input, Option numeric input, Optional memory block input, Optional memory block output]
```

You can pass a memory block "MemBlock" created in ZScript:

```
[FileExecute, "DllName.dll", "FunctionName", "StringArgument", [MemGetSize, "MemBlock"], "MemBlock",]
```

Here's a C++ function in the DLL to receive calls from ZScript, and the memory block:

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" int DLLEXPORT FunctionName(unsigned char* message, double number, void* memblock, void* memblock2)
{
    int mbSize = (int)number; // the second argument has to be a double

    // Read from the memory block via a strstream
    stdstrstream mbStream((char*)memblock, mbSize);

    // Read the first integer written into the memory block by the ZScript
    int val = 0;
    mbStream.read((char*)&val, 4);
}
```

`extern "C"` is to make a C++ function have a 'C' linkage (compiler does not mangle the name) so that ZBrush C code can link to it.